# SonarQube "is provided externally to the method and not sanitized before use"

Tags: java, sonarqube

I am getting this SonarQube Critical Issue and can't find online how to fix it. Anybody knows?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

This issue is raised by a security-related rule, and is telling you that the value in analyticalQuery.query may not be safe to use as-is.

If you know for sure that it is, then mark this a False Positive.

If you're not sure, then the rule description might be helpful (although it's hard to tell just from the message which rule this is).

Comment: Tell me what will be solution for final CallableStatement callableStatement = con.prepareCall("{call PKG_TEST_HEALTH_REPORTS.HEALTH_PROFILE(?,?,?,?,?)}");

Comment: The question is right please look at the error message it reads `"" is provided externally` how can an empty string have sqlSanitization issue. As a matter of fact when I am using sonar it is showing same error message foe every single query; example `strSql="select count(*) cnt from codecorrectins ci,insurance i where ci.InsId=i.insId  and ci.DeleteFlag=0 and i.deleteFlag=0";` how can this query show a message `"" is provided externally to the method and not sanitized before use.` when there is no string concatenation and no params are provided and there are far too many such false +ve to fix